# My cookie values are not updating/changing

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am brand new to JavaScript and I am stuck with this code that I created to display the cookie username and the hit count. The problem is that the cookie values are not being updates when using the setCookies() function, but the same values are outputted again and again. Please help me fix it.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays, visits) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
 var visit = visits.toString()
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; visits=" + visit;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
 var visitCount = getCookie("visits");
 var visitCountConverted = Number(visitCount);
 if (visitCountConverted == "") {
 visitCountConverted = 1;
 }
 else if (visitCountConverted >= 1){
 visitCountConverted += 1;
 }
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCountConverted);
  setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCountConverted);
    } else {
        user = "TheName"; alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCountConverted); setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCountConverted);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this with breakpoints?  Are you sure your setCookie function is being called?

Comment: That is where my confusion beings; I don't know if my Visits value are wrong, if the code is wrong some where, or whether the function is being called itself. I am very new to JavaScript (started about a week ago) and our virtual class gave this an assignment in the first week, now here I am squeezing my brain for the answer. I did notice that it is not being called, but don't know why. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires ;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    var visitCount = getCookie("visits");
    var visitCountConverted = Number(visitCount);
    if (visitCountConverted == "") {
        visitCountConverted = 1;

    }
    else if (visitCountConverted >= 1){
        visitCountConverted += 1;
    }
    if (user == "") {
        user = "TheName";
        setCookie("username", user, 365);

    }
    alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCountConverted);

    setCookie("visits", visitCountConverted, 365);
}
checkCookie();//make sure to call this method so that cookies get set
```

You was not setting the visit counter cookie I have refactored your code as well so please give it a go

Comment: Thank you so much sir/mam. Unfortunately the JavaScript is not executing as there is not alert box popping up. But still thank you for the effort. :)

Comment: I have added a call to checkCookie method at the end please make sure to call it otherwise the fn will never get executed

Comment: I understand what you meant, and I don't know how much I could thank you. I applied your concept to my code (to create a new cookie), and it worked like a charm! Thank you so so much!

Comment: I did do it after a while :D was stuck on a work... :D